# EntityFramework ToListAsync() does not work

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, entity-framework-6

I try to call EF method ToListAsync. But nothing happend - no exception, no timeout just running.

This is my code.

```
        private IQueryable<Place> placeCompleteQuery;
    protected IQueryable<Place> PlaceCompleteQuery
    {
        get
        {
            return this.placeCompleteQuery ?? (this.placeCompleteQuery = this.Context.Places.Include(p => p.Address).
                Include(p => p.CreatedBy).
                Include(p => p.Source).
                Include(p => p.Type.Translations).
                Include(p => p.Ratings));
        }
    }

    public async Task<IList<Place>> GetPlacesByLocationAsync(DbGeography location, int radius)
    {
        List<Place> temporaryResult = PlaceCompleteQuery.Where(p => p.Location.Distance(location) <= radius).
            ToList();

        return await PlaceCompleteQuery.Where(p => p.Location.Distance(location) <= radius).
            ToListAsync();
    }
```

The first sync call of ToList method return result immediately. The second async call of ToListAsync still running with no result nor exception.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suspect that further up your call stack, your code is calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`. If you do this on the UI thread or from an ASP.NET request context, [your code will deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

To fix it, use `await` instead of `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`.

Comment: You are right. I have not have Controller method tagged like async. Thanks for your help.